# SQL build table using results of count(*) from other table

Tags: postgresql, count, create-table

I am building a Pokemon dataset, and want to run some queries on it.
This is the setup of the database:

```
create table pokedex(
    name varchar(20) not null,
    weigth int not null,
    height int not null,
    primary key(name)
);
create table trainer(
    name varchar(20) not null,
    location varchar(20) not null,
    gender varchar(10) not null,
    birth_year int not null,
    primary key(name)
);

create table trainer_pokemon(
    trainer_name varchar(20) not null,
    pokemon_name varchar(20) not null,
    level int not null,
    year_obtained int not null,
    primary key(trainer_name, pokemon_name, level, year_obtained),
    foreign key(trainer_name) references trainer(name),
    foreign key(pokemon_name) references pokedex(name)
);
create table type(
    name varchar(20) not null,
    primary key(name)
);
create table poke_type(
    pokemon_name varchar(20) not null,
    type_name varchar(20) not null,
    primary key(pokemon_name, type_name),
    foreign key(pokemon_name) references pokedex(name),
    foreign key(type_name) references type(name)
);
```

The idea is that the dataset should not have redundant data so if I want to get a table containing most used type of Pokemons for each trainer I need to obtain a table for every type, or atleast that is what I believe atm:

```
with psychics as (
    select trainer_name, count(type_name) psychic from trainer_pokemon as tp
    inner join poke_type as pt on pt.pokemon_name = tp.pokemon_name
    group by tp.trainer_name, pt.type_name
    having pt.type_name = 'Psychic'
),
waters as (
    select trainer_name, count(type_name) water from trainer_pokemon as tp
    inner join poke_type as pt on pt.pokemon_name = tp.pokemon_name
    group by tp.trainer_name, pt.type_name
    having pt.type_name = 'Water'
),
select tp.trainer_name, w.water, p.psychic from trainer_pokemon as tp
inner join waters as w on w.trainer_name = tp.trainer_name
inner join psychics as p on p.trainer_name = tp.trainer_name
group by tp.trainer_name, w.water, p.psychic
```

However, this does not result trainers which do not have pokemon of a specific type (water/psychic in this example).

Is anyone able to point me towards the right direction to build the table of trainers with the amount of times a specific type is in their Pokemon collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you're using a relatively update-to-date version of Postgresql (you've tagged both Mysql and Postgres which are pretty different databases)

```
SELECT tp.trainer_name,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE pt.type_name = 'Psychic') as psychic,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE pt.type_name = 'Water')   as water
FROM trainer_pokemon tp, poke_type pt
WHERE tp.pokemon_name = pt.pokemon_name
GROUP BY 1
```

the query posted in your question would probably get executed as multiple scans of the table, but if you really did want to do it you want to use "LEFT OUTER JOIN"s (the OUTER keyword is optional) do:

```
with psychics as (
    select trainer_name, count(type_name) AS psychic
    from trainer_pokemon as tp
      inner join poke_type as pt on pt.pokemon_name = tp.pokemon_name
    group by tp.trainer_name, pt.type_name
    having pt.type_name = 'Psychic'
), waters as (
    select trainer_name, count(type_name) AS water
    from trainer_pokemon as tp
      inner join poke_type as pt on pt.pokemon_name = tp.pokemon_name
    group by tp.trainer_name, pt.type_name
    having pt.type_name = 'Water'
)
select tp.trainer_name, w.water, p.psychic
from trainer_pokemon as tp
  left join waters as w on w.trainer_name = tp.trainer_name
  left join psychics as p on p.trainer_name = tp.trainer_name
```

or another way that might scale better if you get more than two types:

```
with trained as (
    select trainer_name, pt.type_name, count(*) as num
    from trainer_pokemon as tp
      inner join poke_type as pt on pt.pokemon_name = tp.pokemon_name
    group by tp.trainer_name, pt.type_name
)
select tp.trainer_name, w.num as water, p.num as psychic
from trainer_pokemon as tp
  left join trained as w on tp.trainer_name = w.trainer_name and w.type_name = 'Water'
  left join trained as p on tp.trainer_name = p.trainer_name and p.type_name = 'Psychic'
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot man! I really need to start learning more on what types of join are useful at certain times ;)